# How to achieve [[100, 350], [150, 70], [200, 200], [250, 250]] data structure in typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary, set, angular6

I am trying to use npm natural-spline-interpolator package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/natural-spline-interpolator
Inside this package, I need to pass points as [[100, 350], [150, 70], [200, 200], [250, 250]]. Which data structure should I use to achieve this?

I have already tried to use Set(), Map() data structures.

```
var point = new Set();
var pt;
this.points.forEach(element =>
{
  pt = new Set([element.xAxis, element.yAxis]);
  point.add(pt);
}
```

```
Set() resulted as 

   Set(3) {Set(2), Set(2), Set(2)}
      size: (...)
      __proto__: Set
      [[Entries]]: Array(3)
         0: Set(2)
            value: Set(2)
               size: (...)
               __proto__: Set
               [[Entries]]: Array(2)
                  0: 332.5565912117177
                  1: 407.18204184363304
                  length: 2
         1: Set(2)
         2: Set(2)
         length: 3
```

Should result as:
[[100, 350], [150, 70], [200, 200], [250, 250]]

Comment: Why not just use [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays)?  I must be missing something here.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the arrays would end with {}, But I was assigning the value incorrectly.